# Assistance with invalid direction input

Tags: python

Just need a little guidance in regards to printing out a line when the user inputs an invalid direction. I've tried using if move not in rooms[position] in a few different parts of the code, but I just can't seem to get it function properly. I feel like it's something stupid staring at me, but alas I'm still learning. But basically it's a matter of printing a line when the user enters something other than north, south, east, west, or exit.

Also if there's a better way to write the code as well I'm open to criticism. Appreciate you guys!

```
rooms = {"Great Hall": {"South": "Bedroom"},
     "Bedroom": {"North": "Great Hall", "East": "Cellar"},
     "Cellar": {"West": "Bedroom"},
     }

position = "Great Hall"
move = ""

while True:
    print("You are currently in ", position)
    move = input("\nEnter direction: North, South, East, West, or Exit to finish\n").capitalize()
    if move != "Exit":
        if move in rooms[position]:
            position = rooms[position][move]
            print("You entered", position)
        else:
            print("You see a wall. Try another direction")
    else:
        print("You left the area.")
        break
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issues with the answers below? Please upvote/accept the one you find most helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
rooms = {"Great Hall": {"South": "Bedroom"},
         "Bedroom": {"North": "Great Hall", "East": "Cellar"},
         "Cellar": {"West": "Bedroom"}
        }

validInputs = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West', 'Exit']
position = "Great Hall"
move = ""

while True:
    print("You are currently in ", position)
    move = input("\nEnter direction: North, South, East, West, or Exit to finish\n").capitalize()
    
    if move not in validInputs:
        print('invalid input, please try again')
    elif move != "Exit":
        if move in rooms[position]:
            position = rooms[position][move]
            print("You entered", position)
        else:
            print("You see a wall. Try another direction")
    else:
        print("You left the area.")
        break
```

I hope this is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform checks without nesting, one after another.

```
def start(rooms, position):
    while True:
        print("You are currently in ", position)
        available_moves = rooms[position].keys()  # Getting possible moves.
        move = input(f"\nEnter direction: {', '.join(available_moves)} or Exit to finish\n").capitalize()

        if move == "Exit":  # Fail fast.
            print("You left the area.")
            break
        
        if not move in available_moves:
            # It's not important whether it's one of the directions or
            # just some gibberish.
            # We can't move there, no matter what.
            print('This move isn\'t possible, choose one of the suggested moves.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start({
        "Great Hall": {
            "South": "Bedroom"
        },
        "Bedroom": {
            "North": "Great Hall",
            "East": "Cellar"
        },
        "Cellar": {
            "West": "Bedroom"
        },
    },
    'Great Hall')
```

Answer (score 0):

As to check if valid input, compare move variable towards a list of valid values and output a custom message (see below).

**Played with another thing as well**: since it's a text based game another idea could be to use some kind of prompter like output. The below types each character in the strings with 0,025 sec delay creating a nice effect. Also the below example resets the screen output after each iteration so that it stays neat and clean and doesn't clutter with text.

```py
# Standard library
import os, time, sys


def prompter(message: str, add_dots=False, end="\n") -> None:
    for i, char in enumerate(message):
        print(char, end="", flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.025)
    if add_dots:
        for i in range(0,5):
            print(".", end="", flush=True)
            time.sleep(0.4)
    print(end=end)


def clear() -> None:
    if os.name == "nt":
        os.system("cls")
    else:
        os.system("clear")


def main(rooms: [], position: str) -> None:
    valid_inputs = ["North", "South", "East", "West", "Exit"]
    while True:
        clear()
        print("Valid inputs: " + ", ".join(valid_inputs))
        prompter("You are currently in " + position)
        prompter("Enter direction: ", end="")
        move = input().capitalize()
        if move not in valid_inputs:
            prompter("Incorrect input. Try again", True)
        elif move != "Exit":
            if move in rooms[position]:
                position = rooms[position][move]
                prompter("You entered " + position, True)
            else:
                prompter("You see a wall. Try another direction", True)
        else:
            print("You left the area.")
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rooms = {
        "Great Hall": {
            "South": "Bedroom"
            },
        "Bedroom": {
            "North": "Great Hall",
            "East": "Cellar"
            },
        "Cellar": {
            "West": "Bedroom"
            },
        }
    start_position = "Great Hall"
    main(rooms, start_position)
```